# I have a Jupyter notebook / SciKit model for NBA predictions I want to publish online

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, web-deployment

I built an *NBA prediction model* that outputs results of matches as well as probabilities of victory. Basically, it inputs certain stats about both teams and outputs the likelihood of each team winning.

I built this on a **local Jupyter Notebook**, and I run **one notebook to compile** today's schedule and stats into a csv, and turn this **csv in a panda df** and run it through my model.

There are 2 ways I see this being done but correct me if I'm wrong: 1. Where I run the model locally and update a database with these predictions and my website will pull the data from this database. 2. Ideally, I would like the model to be hosted online and run automatically every day and execute the scripts that I would run locally to compile daily predictions without my input.

I am looking for help on what type of infrastructure I should actually use and what I need to learn to do this on my own. I am currently in the process of learning Django, and some React but I don't seem to be tying the bridge between what I want and what I'm learning.

Any tips on how to go about this journey?

Comment: That's not a valid question here as specified by https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to have it auto update you could have a python script run 24/7 on your web server and set it so that at a certain time it updates.

```
import time

now = time.gmtime()
year, month, day, hour = now[0], now[1], now[2], now[3]
minute = now[4]

if hour == {hour that you would run it at}:
    {Prediction code here}
    Predicted_dub = model.predict({upcoming schedule})
time.sleep(3599)
```

Then you would update the website with those predictions on your website. You could then use Predicted_dub later in your program and show who would win. The time.sleep is in there so it dose not run the same code twice within the same hour and since it is not constantly checking saves some computing resources. I do not know about django but if you wanted to auto update on a flask server you could use app.run(debug=True) to have it auto update without bringing the web server offline. Not sure if this helped or not.

Edit: I am not sure if it is secure to have debug on an actual web server

Comment: this was actually quite helpful, I'm actually debating between building this out using flask at the moment as opposed to Django because I just find it more intuitive. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Honestly I know little to nothing about Flask or Django.  I know flask has a simpler file structure but Django offers a higher skill ceiling.  The choice is yours.  Also I don't think leaving debug on is very secure but i'm not sure